# Build min and max dynamically with keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, mapping

Let's assume we have the following data entries:

```js
const data = [{
    "id": "0",
    "name": {
      "first": "",
      "last": ""
    },
    "nickname": "test",
    "rating": {
      "kw": 1,
      "dc": 2,
      "imp": 3,
      "pat": 4
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": {
      "first": "",
      "last": ""
    },
    "nickname": "test2",
    "rating": {
      "kw": 28,
      "dc": 26,
      "imp": 27,
      "pat": 14
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": {
      "first": "",
      "last": ""
    },
    "nickname": "test3",
    "rating": {
      "kw": 11,
      "dc": 8,
      "imp": 9,
      "pat": 1
    }
  }
];
```

I don't know these object keys within **rating**, so the object could also look like:

```js
{
  "id": "1",
  "name": {
    "first": "",
    "last": ""
  },
  "nickname": "test2",
  "rating": {
    "ab": 28,
    "cd": 26,
    "moep": 27,
    "bla": 14
  }
}
```

I would like to do the following:

- Generate a new object based on the data object keys dynamically (as I don't know them)
- Create a subobject {min: xx, max: xx} for all those object keys

So the result should look like this:

```js
{
  kw: {
    min: 1,
    max: 28
  },
  dc: {
    min: 2,
    max: 26
  },
  imp: {
    min: 3,
    max: 27
  },
  pat: {
    min: 1,
    max: 14
  },

}
```

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reduce the array, and use `Array.forEach()` to iterate the entries, and create/populate the `min` and `max` values of each `rating` key:

```js
const data=[{id:"0",name:{first:"",last:""},nickname:"test",rating:{kw:1,dc:2,imp:3,pat:4}},{id:"1",name:{first:"",last:""},nickname:"test2",rating:{kw:28,dc:26,imp:27,pat:14}},{id:"2",name:{first:"",last:""},nickname:"test3",rating:{kw:11,dc:8,imp:9,pat:1}}];

const result = data.reduce((r, { rating }) => {
  Object.entries(rating).forEach(([k, v]) => {
    if(!r[k]) r[k] = { min: v, max: v }; // if doesn't exist min = max = current value
    else if(v < r[k].min) r[k].min = v; // if current value is less than min -> min = current value
    else if(v > r[k].max) r[k].max = v; // if current value is more than max -> max = current value
  });

  return r;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could `reduce` the array. Loop through the keys of `rating` and set the min and max for each key

```js
const data=[{id:"0",name:{first:"",last:""},nickname:"test",rating:{kw:1,dc:2,imp:3,pat:4}},{id:"1",name:{first:"",last:""},nickname:"test2",rating:{kw:28,dc:26,imp:27,pat:14}},{id:"2",name:{first:"",last:""},nickname:"test3",rating:{kw:11,dc:8,imp:9,pat:1}}];

const output = data.reduce((acc, { rating }) => {
  for (const key in rating) {
    const value = rating[key];
    acc[key] = acc[key] || { min: value, max: value }; // if key doesn't exist, add it
    acc[key].min = Math.min( acc[key].min, value )
    acc[key].max = Math.max( acc[key].max, value )
  }

  return acc;
}, {})

console.log(output)
```

Comment: I get two errors in eslint:

for..in loops iterate over the entire prototype chain, which is virtually never what you want. Use Object.{keys,values,entries}, and iterate over the resulting array.eslint(no-restricted-syntax)

The body of a for-in should be wrapped in an if statement to filter unwanted properties from the prototype.